# Ho to get java date in javascript date format

Tags: javascript, java, simpledateformat, nashorn

I have java date something like this `Wed Feb 01 2017 03:58:56 UTC` and I want to get this is in javascript format like `Wed Feb 01 2017 03:58:56 GMT+0100 (UTC)`.

how can I get this?

Thanks.

Comment: you can use `SimpleDateFormatter` or `DateTimeFormatter` https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html    https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html

Comment: Have you tried searching in Google for this. You will get tons of answer there itself. Please give a try.

Comment: Please may you learn that Java is not JavaScript? To which language are you referring?

Comment: guys obviously I have given try and still searching, and trying the answer..

Comment: `Wed Feb 01 2017 03:58:56 GMT+0100 (UTC)` is javascript date format hence I had tagged the javascript as well for this post.

Simple date format could give me `Wed Feb 01 2017 03:58:56 UTC` and not the way I want.

Nw I'm tryng Nashorn library allows to execute js in java code. 
`engine.eval("new Date()");` gives `[Date 2017-02-01T19:15:57.572Z]`; and `new Date()` function in js gives date as I wanted `Wed Feb 15 2017 19:11:33 GMT+0000 (GMT)`.

Can anybody tell me why nashorn is not giving the o/p as that of  `new Date()` in js ?

Comment: So this gives the expected o/p `engine.eval("print(new Date())");` but it just prints. 

And below code where I want to get the value in variable, it  gives o/p in `[Date 2017-02-01T19:15:57.572Z]` format

            String ss= engine.eval("eval(new Date())").toString();
            System.out.println(ss);

Comment: Your example string `Wed Feb 01 2017 03:58:56 GMT+0100 (UTC)` is incorrect, as `+0100` is not UTC.

Comment: That was just an example.. apologies that I didnt put the correct date..

Comment: I found what I wanted; below is the snippet


`Date d = new Date();

SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd YYYY '00:00:00' 'GMT'Z '('z')'");

format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

String dateStr = format.format(d);
System.out.println(dateStr);`

*Output: Thu Feb 02 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (UTC)*